# Lilypond: How can I write Lyrics without notes?

Tags: lilypond

For some files, I want to add lyrics only, using Lilypond.
And for some texts I want to add ties in the lyrics, I don't know how to format it probably like a normal text. Can I use ties in markup mode, too?

The following code is based on the answer [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/48085/83120) but it has the spacing problem.

```
\version "2.22.1"

\header{
  tagline = ""
}

\layout {
  indent = 0
  ragged-right = ##t
}

\new Score \with {
  \remove "Bar_number_engraver"
  \remove "Time_signature_engraver"
  \remove "Bar_engraver"
}
<< 
  \new Lyrics \with {
  }
  \lyricmode {
      This~works already\break
      This is the second line, but how can I produce it directly below, like in markup mode?\break
      I could use the markup mode, but how could I get~ties~there?

  }
>>
```

[image]

The question linked is similar, but the answers don't solve my problem.
Because of the spacing problem, both answers only work for one single line...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s what \tied-lyric is for. Lo and behold:

```
\markup \column {
  \tied-lyric { "This~works already" }
  \tied-lyric { "This is the second line, but how can I produce it directly below, like in markup mode?" }
  \tied-lyric { "I could use the markup mode, but how could I get~ties~there?" }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works good! Unfortunately there was only one example in the docs and they use it the same I did. Also Bing search for `tied-lyric lilypond` yield my question from today as number two of top search results. That's the reason why I "used it wrongly".

Answer (score 2):

- Update: Although the docs implied it differently, it should be `\tied-lyric{Here go the complete lyrics with~the ties.}`

According to the docs there exist two possibilities and both using `\markup`.
The following example shows the usage of ties in `\markup`-mode.

```
\version "2.22.1"

\header{
  tagline = ""
}

\layout {
  indent = 0
  ragged-right = ##t
}

\markup {
  This\tied-lyric "~"works not so good, but it's good enough...
}
```

The quality is worse than in lyricsmode though:
[image]

The [docs](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.21/Documentation/notation/stanzas) also show how to add stanzas in `\markup`-mode, which works without notes, but same poor quality ties:
[image]

- [Here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lilypond-user/2017-04/msg00485.html) I found a discussion about tweaking the poor quality tie.

Comment: The quality is worse because you’re using the command \tied-lyric wrongly. The argument to the function are the whole lyrics, not just the tie.